Apache Beam Dataflow Pipeline Stalls Periodically
I'm running an Apache Beam pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow that reads messages from an MQTT broker and processes them. However, I'm encountering an issue where the pipeline processes a batch of messages for under a millisecond and then stalls for 10 seconds before processing the next batch. This cycle repeats consistently. I've written some code that resemples the production environment as shown bellow. But instead of writing a file and upload to GCP I instead log the message and just throw it away. For full disclosure of k8s setup, MQTT broker etc., the entire test repo can be found here: https://github.com/jesperbrowall/gcp_test_archiver
Software Components

UDP Sender: Sends messages to the middleware at a fixed interval.
Middleware: Receives UDP messages, publishes them to an MQTT broker.
MQTT Broker: VerneMQ running on a Kubernetes cluster.
Apache Beam Dataflow Pipeline: Reads messages from the MQTT broker and processes them.

Code and Configuration
UDP Sender
The UDP sender sends messages to a specified IP and port at regular intervals. The IP is a dummy.
import socket
import time

UDP_IP = "11.11.111.11"
UDP_PORT = 6915
MESSAGE = b"some_message"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # Internet  # UDP

start = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    print(i)

    time.sleep(0.01)
    fsd = sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

total_time = time.time() - start

**Middleware **
The middleware receives UDP messages and publishes them to an MQTT broker. It logs each received message and waits for a short timeout after publishing. The IP is a dummy.
import socket
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
import logging
import google.cloud.logging


logging_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
logging_client.setup_logging()  # type: ignore

logging.error("MW MESSAGE: START APP")

client = mqtt_client.Client(protocol=mqtt_client.MQTTv5)
client.connect("11.111.111.111", 1883)

logging.error("MW MESSAGE: LOOP FOREVER")

udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 6915))
logging.error("MW MESSAGE: BIND UDP")

udp_socket.setblocking(True)
client.loop_start()

while True:
    logging.error("MW MESSAGE: ENTERED LOOP")
    data_raw, _ = udp_socket.recvfrom(65535)
    decoded_message = data_raw.decode("utf-8")
    logging.error(f"MW MESSAGE: {decoded_message}")
    message_published_response = client.publish("raw", decoded_message, qos=1)
    message_published_response.wait_for_publish(timeout=0.001)

Apache Beam Dataflow Pipeline
The Dataflow pipeline reads messages from the MQTT broker and processes them. We initially implemented batch processing but later simplified it to process messages individually with a short delay to simulate processing time.
package com.datavarde.app;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mqtt.MqttIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;

public class ArchivePipeline {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
                                .withValidation().as(PipelineOptions.class);
                Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
                pipeline.apply(MqttIO.read()
                .withConnectionConfiguration(MqttIO.ConnectionConfiguration.create(
                  "tcp://11.111.111.111:1883",
                  "raw")
                ))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<byte[], Void>() {
                        @ProcessElement
                        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                            byte[] message = c.element();
                            // Log to the console
                            System.out.println("Processing: " + new String(message));
                        }
                    }));
                pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();

        }
}

Question
How can I further diagnose and resolve this problem so that dataflow pipeline do not stall?
I've tried to:

Increased Worker Count: Increased the maximum number of workers and enabled auto-scaling to handle the load. Expected it to work but obeserved same behaviuor as described above.
Run Locally: A collegue of mine said he initially tried it locally. Expected it not to work, but it worked perfectly.


Did you see the autoscaling scales up the number of workers? without knowing the Dataflow job log, it is hard to check what is going on. Hopefully, you can check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline and https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-streaming-stragglers
